# Label not change in callback swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to change my label text after getting a response from the server but it doesn't change after getting a response from server!!

here is my code :

```
func getOrderCost() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.customView?.setOrderPriceEstimate(price: "۰")
        var price = 10
        if let p_code = self.customView?.getPromotionCode() {

            self.orderPriceObject.promotion_code = p_code
        }  
        self.registerOrderVM.getOrderPriceEstimation(orderInfo: self.orderPriceObject).asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { (response) in

            if let res = response as? [String: Int], let p = res["price_with_added_value"] {

                self.customView?.setOrderPriceEstimate(price: "cost : \(p)")
            }
        }, onError: { (error) in

            self.view.showMessage(error.localizedDescription, type: .error, options: [.hideOnTap(true)])
        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

and this is the `setOrderPriceEstimate` function in `customView` :

```
public func setOrderPriceEstimate(price: String) {

    self.orderCostLbl.text = price
}
```

Comment: are you creating a label programmatically inside your custom view ???
if yes then try reloading that view
using  self.view.setNeedsDisplay() or 
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Are you always receive response from server in required format?

Comment: @RomanPodymov yea I don't have problem with the response

Comment: @Mohsenmokhtari Why self.customView is optional? Can it be nil?

Answer (score 0):

Making  **DispatchQueue.main.async**  outer doesn't guarantee that code inside **getOrderPriceEstimation**   will run in  main queue as code inside getOrder may be in other thread

```
    func getOrderCost() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.customView?.setOrderPriceEstimate(price: "۰")
            var price = 10
            if let p_code = self.customView?.getPromotionCode() {
                self.orderPriceObject.promotion_code = p_code
            }



            self.registerOrderVM.getOrderPriceEstimation(orderInfo: self.orderPriceObject).asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { (response) in


                if let res = response as? [String: Int], let p = res["price_with_added_value"] {

              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.customView?.setOrderPriceEstimate(price: "cost : \(p)")

                  }
                }

            }, onError: { (error) in

                self.view.showMessage(error.localizedDescription, type: .error, options: [.hideOnTap(true)])
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

        }

    }
```

verify if p exists or not

```
if let res = response as? [String: Int], let p = res["price_with_added_value"] {

                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.customView?.setOrderPriceEstimate(price: "cost : \(p)")          }
            }
     else
    {
       print("res or p is not found")
    }
```

Also check if customView is nil

Comment: it is updating only one time

Comment: what do you mean by 1 time

Comment: I don't have any  problem with the response, I can see response in debug mode, my problem is with label

Comment: you mean   self.customView?.setOrderPriceEstimate(price: "۰") is working

Comment: but  self.customView?.setOrderPriceEstimate(price: "cost : \(p)") is not working ????

Comment: Also check if customView is nil

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.customView?.setOrderPriceEstimate(price: "cost : \(p)")
    }
```

I think you have to update UI in main thread.

Comment: it is updating only one time

Comment: if let res = response as? [String: Int], let p = res["price_with_added_value"] { debug and make sure value of p is available.

Comment: I am sure with the response

Comment: is customView subclass of UIView , can provide code of customView